# Create a list of multiple matrices with list instead of using a for loop

Tags: r

I am working with a precipitation data set that is organised in an array (dimensions are `150 150 80`). The third dimension respresents the single time steps.
Additonally I have a matrix called "mask" of dimensions `150 150`. The goal is to multiply this matrix with every single time step so that at the end there are 80 (which is equal to `ntime`) resulting matrices.

This can easily be done using a loop:

```
for (i in 1:ntime) {
  assign(paste0("matrix_out",i), PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask)
}
```

The thing is that afterwards I have to deal with 80 matrices, called "matrix_out1, matrix_out1, ..., matrix_out80". It is possible to further process these data, but not very elegant though.

I am sure that there is a more handy way by using a list instead of creating 80 single objects. So far I am not so familiar with working with lists.

Does anybody can give me a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add each loop result to a list:

```
matlist <- list()
for (i in 1:ntime) {
  matlist[[i]] = assign(paste0("matrix_out",i), PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask)
}
```

Right, I forgot about the matrices saved to the environment.  You can eliminate that with:

```
matlist <- list()
for (i in 1:ntime) {
  matlist[[i]] = PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask
  names(matlist)[i] = paste0("matrix_out",i)
}
```

So the stand-alone matrices are not created

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This works and creates the desired list. But is also creates the ```ntime``` single matrices. Is there a way to avoid this or to delete only those objects from the global environment afterwards?

Edit: Found a way to them afterwards: ```rm(list=ls(pattern="matrix.out"))```.

Comment: rm(list = ls(pattern = 'matrix_.out')) will delete these objects from global environment.
Or use this from without assigning  to global environmnt matlist[[paste0("matrix_out",i)]] = PRECIPITATION[,,i]*mask

Comment: @badalovi: thanks for the second hint, this is exactly what I was for looking for!